# Revert to old Chrome profile icon / avatar upper left corner

Tags: chrome

Restarted Chrome and the old profile avatar in upper left corner was gone.

With constant use of multiple profiles for various testing etc. I have grown custom to quickly recognize which profile I am on by looking at upper left corner. It is also a quick way to bring various opened profiles to front (as all icons on alt+tab etc. are equal).

The new version: "*name*" in upper right corner with a multilayer navigation and a lot of extra information. Sure good for some, but not for me.

How to revert?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find version go to `chrome://chrome` in Google-Chrome, or say:

```
$ google-chrome --version
```

### Version < 43 ]

At least for now, go to:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-new-avatar-menu
```

Select *Disabled* and restart browser.

---

### Version [ 44, 46.0.2490.??]

As for version 44 to 46.0.?* the above tweak does not work. But 
 add `--disable-new-avatar-menu` to startup:

```
$ google-chrome --disable-new-avatar-menu
```

### Version [ 46.0.2490.71 >

As of now they have removed this option as well. If one use the `--disable-new-avatar-menu` option the profile-icon/avatar is present, but the drop down menu is gone. As a quirk the profile-selection page (where one can launch another profile):

```
chrome://user-manager/
```

is disabled as well.

Yes. One can right-click the *profile-name* to get a quick switch to other profile, but avatar is gone. Have to see it there is a way to hack it.

Comment: Funny that after enabling and disabling this feature, the avatar image can (only) then be switched to the Google account image.

Comment: not work anymore :-(

Comment: @zx1986: I was late to update Chrome. See if update works.